# why my build returns me an error (Aeplugin)

Tags: javascript, c++, visual-studio, build, after-effects

trying to build Plugin for Ae
The build stop at a error code:

> Error  C3861   'LoadStringFromFile': identifier not found

and

> Error  C2065   'effectContent': undeclared identifier

the code is here:

```
#ifdef AE_PLUGIN
    string filename = globalDataP->pluginFilename;
    int pos = (int)filename.find_last_of(".");
    if (pos > 0) filename = filename.substr(0, pos);
    filename = globalDataP->pluginPath + filename + ".gmic";
    effectContent = gmic_parse_single(effectContent, effectData);
    string effectContent = LoadStringFromFile(filename);
    if (myGlobalDataP) {
        myGlobalDataP->effectContent = effectContent;
        myGlobalDataP->effectData = effectData;
    }
    bool hasContent = effectContent != "";
```

But I am not really a coder, thank you for your help...

the entire Plugin cpp could be found here

https://github.com/GreycLab/gmic-community/blob/master/gmic_plugin/src/GMIC_AE/gmic_ae_tool.cpp

Thank you

Comment: The first error is saying that the `LoadStringFromFile()` method hasn't been defined, so it can't be called. The second error is saying that the `effectContent` variable hasn't been declared. That's the only help we can offer given the small snippet of code shown.

Comment: TY Rory, what I don't understand is that this Aeplugin has already been build way before, I am just trying to add multi frame rendering with the new Adobe Sdk flag, I think I don't understand how to build in Visual basic studio, by the way by ignoring the C++ or JScript error...

Comment: This is the Aeplugin from the  GMIC project from here By tobias Fleischer https://github.com/GreycLab/gmic-community/tree/master/gmic_plugin

Comment: In fact I am trying to build the Gmic_AE ccp  https://github.com/GreycLab/gmic-community/blob/master/gmic_plugin/src/GMIC_AE/gmic_ae_tool.cpp